# Java Looping Meters Conversion Program

Tags: java

I cannot figure out how to have the program loop through the Conversion Menu and then return to the Main Menu from choice "4 Return" as shown in the example.

---

Example of what the program output might look like:

Main Menu

1. Enter Distance
2. Quit the program

> Please enter your choice: 1
>
> Enter a distance in meters: 500

Conversion Menu

1. Convert to kilometers
2. Convert to inches
3. Convert to feet
4. Return

> Enter your choice: 1
>
> 500 meters is 0.5 kilometers

Conversion Menu

1. Convert to kilometers
2. Convert to inches
3. Convert to feet
4. Return

> Enter your choice: 3
>
> 500 meters is 1640.5 feet

Conversion Menu

1. Convert to kilometers
2. Convert to inches
3. Convert to feet
4. Return

> Enter your choice: 4

Main Menu

1. Enter Distance
2. Quit the program

> Please enter your choice: 2
>
> Good Bye!

---

I've found multiple solutions for the program when it doesn't include the main menu and the looping back to it but I can't seem to find anything on this.

Here's what I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice;
int option;
double meters = 0;
conversionControl();
choice = keyboard.nextInt();    
    switch (choice) {
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("\nEnter a Distance in Meters:"); 
            meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
            break;
        case 2:
            quitProgram();
            break;
        default:
            showError("Please Enter a Valid Option");
            conversionControl();
            option = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (option == 1) {
                    System.out.println("\nEnter a Distance in Meters:"); 
                    meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
                }
                else if ( option == 2) {
                    quitProgram();
                }
            break;
    }
    do{ 
        menu();
        choice = keyboard.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1: 
                showKilometers(meters);
                break;
            case 2: 
                showInches(meters);
                break;
            case 3: 
                showFeet(meters);
                break;
            case 4: 
                conversionControl();
                option = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (option == 1) {
                    System.out.println("\nEnter a Distance in Meters:"); 
                    meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
                }
                else if ( option == 2) {
                    quitProgram();
                }
                break;
            default:
                showError("Please Enter a Valid Option");
                menu();
                choice = keyboard.nextInt();
                break;
        }
    } while(choice != 0); {
    }
}
```

I guess I did figure my own way out but I keep thinking it isn't the correct way or there's an easier way. Plus, some errors occur when testing some inputs (mainly the the showError method calls will output either the incorrect menu or it will just close the program after so many wrong inputs).

Any help/constructive criticism would be greatly appreciated. I'm somewhat new to coding (know HTML) and new to to this site as well.

Thank you!
Bob

Comment: You would have it lot easier with breaking down your code in several small methods, than this big block. ie, a method to show each menu, one to read the input, one to handle a choice for a menu, etc .. Also you could have a Menu class.

Answer (score 1):

As it look like an exercise I won't give you a complete code, but a pseudo code to help you understand the strategy here.

To clarify, I'll name your first menu as `mainMenu` and the second as `convMenu`.

You have already implemented the good strategy for the `convMenu`. The idea is to make a loop, and exist only when the user tells you so. What you are missing is to do the same for the `mainMenu` and to think the `convMenu` as a sub-menu of the `mainMenu`. Which means when you are in the `convMenu` you are not outside of the `mainMenu`.

```
//That's pseudo code
do {
    displayMainMenu();
    readUserInput();
    switch(userInput) {
        case 1 : 
            //here you put your convMenu
            do {
                displayConvMenu();
                readUserInput();
                switch(userInput) {
                    case 1, 2, 3 :
                       doConvertion();
                    case 4 :
                        exitConvMenu = true;
                    default :
                        //wrong input display a message and loop
                }
            } while(!exitConvMenu)
        case 2:
            exitMainMenu = true;
        default :
            //wrong input display a message and loop
    }
} while(!exitMainMenu)
```

Comment: @MauricePerry It's pseudo code, that's why I didn't put any `break;`

Comment: @MauricePerry what do you mean ?

Comment: it's misleading

Comment: I don't think so cause I made it clear that it's pseudo-code, which there will be a lot of instruction missing, it's just to show the structure. Or I'm wrong and I still don't understand what you mean... Why would the missing `break;` instruction misleading in case 1, but not misleading in all the other case ?

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down the code in little pieces usually makes it easier to understand and debug. Divide and conquer! Here is how I would do it:

First create a `Menu` class which represent a menu, it can print the Menu on screen and check that a choice is valid:

```
class Menu {
    private String title;
    private List<String> choices;
    private String prompt;

    public Menu(String title, List<String> choices, String prompt) {
        this.title = title;
        this.choices = choices;
        this.prompt = prompt;
    }

    public boolean isChoiceAllowed(int i) {
        return i > 0 && i <= choices.size();
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println(title);
        for(int i=0; i<choices.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("  " + (i+1) + ". " + choices.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println(prompt);
    }
}
```

Then define your 2 menus:

```
private static final Menu mainMenu = new Menu(
    "Main Menu",
    Arrays.asList("Enter Distance", "Quit the program"),
    "Please enter your choice");

private static final Menu conversionMenu = new Menu(
    "Conversion Menu",
    Arrays.asList("Convert to kilometers", "Convert to inches", "Convert to feet", "Return"),
    "Please enter your choice");
```

Have a method to read the user input:

```
private static int readUserInput() {
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();
    // Check if input is valid, if not call back readUserInput() until a valid input is given
    if(!currentMenu.isChoiceAllowed(input)) {
        System.out.println("Please Enter a valid option");
        return readUserInput();
    }
    return input;
}
```

Have a method to handle choices in the Main Menu

```
private static void handleMainMenuChoice(int choice) {
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("\nEnter a Distance in Meters:");
            meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
            // Set the current menu to be the Conversion Menu
            currentMenu = conversionMenu;
            break;
        case 2:
            quitProgram();
            break;
    }
}
```

Have a method to handle choices in the Conversion Menu

```
private static void handleConversionMenuChoice(int choice) {
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            showKilometers(meters);
            break;
        case 2:
            showInches(meters);
            break;
        case 3:
            showFeet(meters);
            break;
        case 4:
            // Set the current menu to be the Main Menu
            currentMenu = mainMenu;
            break;
    }
}
```

Have a method to handle the user choice and dispatch it to the appropriate method above:

```
private static void handleChoice(int choice) {
    if(currentMenu == mainMenu) {
        handleMainMenuChoice(choice);
    } else {
        handleConversionMenuChoice(choice);
    }
}
```

Then tie it up together:

```
private static double meters;
private static Menu currentMenu;
private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

<Insert menu definitions here>

public static void main(String[] args) {

    currentMenu = mainMenu;

    int choice;
    while (true) {
        // Show the current menu
        currentMenu.show();
        // Read the user input
        choice = readUserInput();
        // Handle the user choice
        handleChoice(choice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice = 0;
        int option;
        double meters = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean exit = false;
        while(!exit) {

            System.out.println("\nEnter your choice :Enter Distance.. click1\r\n" + 
                    "\r\n" + 
                    "Quit the program.. click2"); 
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();    
            switch (choice) {
                case 1: 
                    System.out.println("\nEnter a Distance in Meters:"); 
                    meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Conversion Menu\r\n" + 
                            "\r\n" + 
                            "Convert to kilometers .. click1\r\n" + 
                            "\r\n" + 
                            "Convert to inches .. click2\r\n" + 
                            "\r\n" + 
                            "Convert to feet .. click3\r\n" + 
                            "\r\n" + 
                            "Return.... .. click4"); 
                    int choice1 = keyboard.nextInt();
                    switch(choice1) {
                        case 1:
                            showKilometers(meters);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            showInches(meters);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            showFeet(meters);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            exit = true;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    exit = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this could be a simple solution to your problem